# How to stop leather from making stain on clothes with light colors

Tags: clothing

Some clothes or accessories made from leather tend to create (dark) stain or spots on clothes, of course especially on clothes having light colors. Some spots can be removed  easily, others not.

Examples: Wearing leather shoes or a leather belt with light trousers, using a bag made from leather, wearing gloves and a white shirt, wearing a leather jacket.

Of course, this all depends on the leather used and the type of cloth or accessory, and the color and material of the clothes becoming stain etc. Especially, I noticed that this happens with different kinds of leather, but not with all products made from leather.

There are a number of workarounds such as:

- Don't wear clothes with light colors.
- Don't use shoes, belts, bags etc. made from leather.
- Use the cloth or accessory made from leather 10 years or longer and hope that after such a long time it will have stopped making stain or spots.

But what can be done to stop something made from leather from creating stain or spots?

**Examples:**

Trousers (cotton), stain from a leather belt; after washing, without any special treatment to remove the stain:

[image: trousers with stain from leather belt]

Piece of cloth, slightly wet (rain!), after rubbing at a leather bag:

[image: cloth]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***It appears as if the leather has not been cured or sealed properly. Here are some methods you could use:***

- *Vinegar to clean the stains off the clothing. This should disable the stains, but may need a vinegar soak for a while. Using vinegar should not ruin regular fabrics.*

  - *Using other acids like lemon juice, etc I do not know if work, but they should. Mixing the acid with baking soda should make a sort of scouring powder if you are trouble removing the stain with just the acid.*

---

**Other methods are:**

- *Sealing the Leather again. I was under the influence that leather was suppose to be sealed. By sealing it again you could try to avoid this problem.*
- *Also washing the leather before using it. Cleaning the leather a couple of time before using may work.*
- *Wearing a light weight  garment over the leather, and in a way to protect the other clothing may work if none of the other methods work.*

**Stains can also be avoided by knowing the composition of the stain:**

- Know if the stain is from dye, normal leather stains or some sort of chemical used to dye or etc the leather?

This way you know what course of action to take for stain removal. Dye may not come out easily or at all.

Answer (score 2):

My white shirt got stained with a leather backpack and I first put chlorine and it didn't work, then on one side I put vinegar and nothing and on the other side tried the Carbona ink and crayons stain remover and it worked almost immediately!!! Just apply and rub with a wet cloth.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that Brown leather causes the most staining. I had two brown leather belts and when my clothes got wet from sweat the brown leather dye stained my trousers and seeped through and stained my shirts. I didn't noticed for a few days. I have found that leather dye stain are very hard to remove. I think oxygen containing stain removers work best on them. Use patent leather goods instead which are plastic coated leather. Or artificial leather which is made from fabric and coated with plastic to look like leather. I now use fake leather belts.